# How do I print odd and even numbers on two seperate tables in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2012, modulus

I've got this far in my SQL code. I am struggling to get my data to be printed in two separate table according to odd and even numbers. Thanks in advance for your input. I really appreciate it.

```
DECLARE
  @empNM CHAR(15),
  @empID INT,
  @reportsTO INT
DECLARE
  emp CURSOR dynamic FOR 
SELECT Employee_NM, Employee_ID, ReportsTo
    FROM employeetable
    ORDER BY Employee_ID ASC
OPEN emp
FETCH NEXT
  FROM emp
  INTO @empNM, @empID, @reportsTO;
PRINT 'name           id          boss'

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
IF (@empID % 2 = 0)
BEGIN
  SET @empNM = CONVERT(CHAR,CAST(@empNM AS VARCHAR),1)
  PRINT CAST(@empNM AS VARCHAR)+CAST(@empID AS VARCHAR)+SPACE(11)+CAST(@reportsTO AS varCHAR)


  FETCH NEXT
    FROM emp
    INTO @empNM, @empID, @reportsTO;
END;
ELSE 

BEGIN
 SET @empNM = CONVERT(CHAR,CAST(@empNM AS VARCHAR),1)
  PRINT CAST(@empNM AS VARCHAR)+CAST(@empID AS VARCHAR)+SPACE(11)+CAST(@reportsTO AS varCHAR)
  FETCH NEXT
    FROM emp
    INTO @empNM, @empID, @reportsTO;
END;
CLOSE emp;
DEALLOCATE emp;
```

This is the desired outcome...

[image: This is the supposed outcome]

Comment: Use [a Modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) *in the [WHERE clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx)* of the query itself. Then all the ugly cursor/procedural code can be removed; and a result-set (or sets) directly returned. CURSORS should be a 'last effort', usually when needing to apply a result-set immediately, which I doubt is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using C# looping through data. With SQL, you must work on the whole set of data, hence no cursor. (in most cases)

You must execute 1 insert for each table:

```
Insert Into TOdd(Name, Id, Boss) Select Name, Id, Boss From T Where id % 2 = 1
Insert Into TEven(Name, Id, Boss) Select Name, Id, Boss From T Where id % 2 = 0
```

See SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/212a9/1/0